# ¿Es posible mantener el formato del texto de un textarea al insertarlo en MySQL y recuperarlo?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo una web que tiene una sección de noticias. La página va a tener un sector administrativo en el cual personas (con casi nulo conocimiento de computadoras) van a escribir noticias.

La idea es que las noticias tengan formato (por formato me refiero a los saltos de linea).

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? Básicamente quiero que mi código *PHP* entienda cada espacio como un *breakline* en el *insert*.

**Edito:**

Quizás no estoy siendo muy claro. La idea es que alguien teclee algo como:

> Viacom, quinto conglomerado de medios a nivel mundial y con un valor de mercado de US$ 14.700 millones, también participa de los estudios Paramount y DreamWorks, y tiene estudio propio en el barrio porteño de Palermo.
>
> El acuerdo todavía está pendiente de las últimas firmas, advirtieron fuentes locales, además de requerir la aprobación del Ente Nacional de Comunicaciones (Enacom). Ya a principios de septiembre el número uno de Viacom en la región, Pierluigi Gazzolo, se había reunido con Miguel de Godoy, titular del organismo de control.

Y ese *breakline* se vea igual en el *insert* de *SQL* para que a la hora de poner la noticia en la web, tome el formato correspondiente.

Comment: Es decir si te ponen: Hola soy Juan y estoy escribiendo esto. ¿Que te apareciera cada una de las palabras en una línea distinta?

Comment: No puedo escribir bien acá. Basicamente quiero que alguien escriba en un text area con formato y parrafos y que al enviar se traduzca en codigo para el insert. Ejemplo "Parrafo de noticia 1 (TECLA ENTER) Parrafo de noticia 2", y al subir al sql, se suba con el formato correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Y que tendría que aparecer después?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir la nueva explicación. Tienes un botón de editar justo debajo de la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que quizás no me estoy explicando muy bien :P. La idea es que cada vez que hagan un break line con enter se reemplaze solo con un \n

Comment: @Nick, lo más probable es que sí se estén grabando los saltos de línea, pero que no los estés mostrando correctamente luego de leerlos de la base. ¿Podrás mostrar la parte relevante del código y cómo aparece en la base de datos? Quizás te conviene probar de mostrar lo que lees de la base en una etiqueta `<pre> ... </pre>`, que respeta los saltos de línea.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es por eemplo usar un plugin de javascript que te ponga los textareas como si fueran ediotres de texto.

Answer (score 3):

No sé si es esto a lo que te refieres exactamente. Teniendo un string almacenado como el siguiente:

```
"Hola soy Juan \n tengo una bicicleta \n y me voy con mis amigos a jugar \n al futbol"
```

y un `textarea` con un `id`:

```
<textarea id="miTextArea" style=""></textarea>
```

puedes usar la propiedad `word-break: break-all;` de CSS para que respete los `\n` como salto de línea.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Hola soy Juan \n tengo una bicicleta \n y me voy con mis amigos a jugar \n al futbol"
```

```css
#myTextarea{
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-family: monospace; 
  height: 15em; 
  resize: none;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" style=""></textarea>
```

**EDIT:** A la hora de insertar el string en la base de datos simplemente inserta el texto tal y como lo insertan los usuarios en el textarea. Parece ser que MySQL si que guarda el formato del texto en cuanto a saltos de línea se refiere.

Referencia: [Adding a line break in MySQL INSERT INTO text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902888/adding-a-line-break-in-mysql-insert-into-text)

Comment: Eso me sirve muchisimo! Aunque para el siguiente paso. A mi me interesa el paso previo, cuando una persona escribe un texto, presiona "Enviar" y se genera un insert. Creo que los \n no aparecen cuando se envia a la db

Comment: @Nick Voy a intentar hacer un código para eso también. Dame unos minutos.

Comment: @Nick que db usas, yo he usado `MySQL Server` y `SQL Server` y en ambas bases de datos se guardan los saltos cuando he hecho una inserción, eso si esos saltos de linea no se me muestran en el campo de la db, esos deberían aparecer cuando vas a mostrar nuevamente el texto en un `textarea`

Comment: @Nick Parece ser que si que deja insertar datos directamente con salto de línea en la base de datos. Te he puesto una referencia a Stackoverflow en inglés, sin embargo, comprueba por tí mismo a insertar directamente un valor con salto de línea. A mí en MySQL Server si que me ha dejado.

Answer (score 3):

Con [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) lo puedes conseguir **[ver demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6af76926fd57df3a9551f5945c450e68dabcdd44)**:

```
$cadena = "Esto\r\nes\n\runa\ncadena\r";
echo nl2br($cadena);

// Resultado:
// Esto<br />
// es<br />
// una<br />
// cadena<br />
```

Si recibes la cadena de texto de la base de datos y lo metes dentro de un `<textarea>` no tienes que hacer nada, ya que lo guarda con todo el formato y se muestra como lo haya introducido el usuario. Lo contrario tienes que usar `nl2br()`.

**Nota seguridad:**

Te recomiendo de guardar los textos del usuario, sin transformarlo de ninguna manera en la base de datos.

Solo y siempre cuando recibas de la base de datos el texto del usuario y lo quieras mostrar en tu web usa también [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

> Convierte entidades HTML de nuevo en caracteres especiales.

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($texto_de_la_base_de_datos);

<textarea><php echo $string; ?></textarea>

// ------ //

<p><php echo nl2br($string); ?></p>
```

Comment: Igual eso sería considerando que ya sé el texto. En la web tengo un while que carga cada row de una noticia en la base de datos.

Comment: @Nick - No entiendo... como que ya sabes el texto? Si recibes el texto de la base de datos lo metes en la función `nl2br()`.. esa es la idea tuya no?

Comment: Es que no recibo el texto, es el texto que una persona envia a la base de datos, copiar el formato del text area de la web en el insert del sql.

Comment: @Nick - Entonces no tienes que hacer nada... el formato se guarda tal cual en la base de datos... solo cuando quieras mostrar el texto usas esta función...

Comment: Oh! Voy a probar con esto y vengo comentar :). Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Con este estilo puedes hacer que mantenga el formato con el que se guarde en la bd.

```
#myTextarea {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```